# Can't get destroy to work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Fairly new to rails and can't seem to get this simple destroy action working. All it does is redirect to the mod panel index page and doesn't destroy the record. Do I need to call `.destroy` in the destroy method? or is there something I'm missing?

mod_approval controller

```
def index
    @guide          = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
    @check_category = CheckCategory.where(guide_id: @guide.id).all
    @category       = Guide.friendly.find(@guide.id).categories.new
end

def destroy
    redirect_to guide_mod_panel_mod_approval_index_path(@guide)
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
match '/guides/:guide_id/mod-panel/approve/reject' => 'mod_approval#destroy', :via => :delete, as: :guide_mod_panel_approve_destroy
```

index.html.erb

```
 <% @check_category.each do |category| %>
    <%= link_to "Reject", guide_mod_panel_approve_destroy_path(@guide, category), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"} %><br>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the record from the database, then you can call destroy on the object, you can do this

```
def destroy
  guide = Guide.find(params[:guide_id])
  category = guide.categories.find(params[:id])
  category.destroy
  redirect_to guide_mod_panel_mod_approval_index_path(guide) 
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep. Quick question, can I just  call `.destroy` in the link_to (or something similar). removing the need for the destroy method in the controller?

Comment: No, deleting record is an action, therefore you need to define an `action` in the controller.

Comment: I spoke too soon haha. I get the error `Couldn't find CheckCategory with 'id'=` the params id isnt passing I think.

Comment: check the url against `guide_mod_panel_mod_approval_index` by running `rake routes`

Comment: The url is /guides/:guide_id/mod-panel/approve. I though it would grab the id from `category` in the link_to - `guide_mod_panel_approve_destroy_path(@guide, category)` not sure what the param for it would be though. Or do I have to put the id in the destroy URL like so /guides/:guide_id/mod-panel/approve/destroy/:id

Comment: Yes, can you paste your routes for guides and category controller

Comment: Works fine now I added `:id` in the delete route. Out of curiosity do you know if I can grab the `category` param passed in the Link_to?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to destroy object before:

```
def destroy
 @destroyed_object.destroy # or Model.destroy(params[:id])
 redirect_to guide_mod_panel_mod_approval_index_path(@guide)
end
```